# Entity Framework 6 and SQLite - cannot create entry with PK of entry deleted before

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using the Entity Framework 6 and the SQLite database (System.Data.SQLite.EF6), but I cannot create an entry with same primary key instantly after deleting it. For example:

My model of entity:

```
public class Person
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

STEPS:

1) I insert the instance of this entity person1 (with Id = 1) into my table of persons.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   context.Create(person1);
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

2) Afters some tome I clear the entire Persons table with:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(string.Format("DELETE FROM `PersonModels`"));
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

3) I try to add entry with same primary key as entry from 1st step: person2 (with Id = 1)

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   context.Create(person2);
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But in 3rd step, `SaveChangesAsync()` fails with

> System.InvalidOperationException: The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'DbModels.PersonModel' have the same primary key value.

When I add some other entry after clearing the table (with different primary key) and then add entry from 1st step, it works fine and both entries are saved without exceptions.

I added a breakpoint directly before creating of a new entry (after table is cleared) and checked the Persons table by external tool and table is empty (so there is no entry with id = 1).

UPDATE:
Extended DbContexte + implementation of my Create method:

```
    public DbSet<PersonModel> Persons { get; set; }

    public T Create<T>(T entity)
        where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            GetDbSetForType<T>().Add(entity);
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    private DbSet<T> GetDbSetForType<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(PersonModel)) return Persons as DbSet<T>;
        //...my other types
        throw new Exception("Type not found in db");
    }
```

Comment: context.Create(person2) - is this your own method? Because I don't remember EF has it. If so - can you show it?

Comment: @Toddams oh, sorry, I added body of my Create method to the question

Comment: If you delete all entries from PersonModels, you could use this instead: `await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE 'PersonModels'"));` Would that work for you?

Comment: @LocEngineer SQLite doesn't support the TRUNCATE command (from offical documentation: _Unfortunately, we do not have TRUNCATE TABLE command in SQLite but you can use SQLite DELETE command to delete complete data from an existing table._)

Comment: Too bad. However, accoring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854906/deleting-an-entry-and-releasing-from-unique-key-index you might be able to solve this by running your delete command in a transaction and commiting that transaction.

Comment: I've written some (mainly copied yours) code and when using individual data contexts for each operation everything works. However, when 1st and 3rd steps were made in the same data context I got the same exception as yours. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @PatrykSpytkowski thanks, but I'm using two instances of context (first one for table clear and the different/new instance for creating entry), but still same exception (it looks crazy, because in moment of instantiating the second DataContext, my table in the database is empty - I checked  it using breakpoints and external tool...)

Comment: @DominikPalo But if you're using same instance for both inserts, your data context 'don't know' you have cleared db and still keeps cached object with your PK. That's only thing I can figure out...

Comment: @DominikPalo Hmm, so maybe it's a matter of some sort of caching inside SQLite provider? What if you try to delete PersonModel records manually using DbSet.RemoveRange? I understand it will be slower, but then you'll know that problem is somewhere on the EF or provider side. My test mentioned before used MS SQL database and everything was ok...

Answer (score 0):

EF database contexts maintain a list of objects that it retrieved from the database in-memory until it is destroyed or unloaded.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    var person1 = new Person { Id = 1 };
    ctx.Persons.Add(person1);
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

    await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(string.Format("DELETE FROM `PersonModels`"));

    // This is the secret
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Detach(person1);

    ctx.Persons.Add(person1)
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using separate contexts (after I clear the Persons table, I dispose context and create a new instance of context for adding an entry). Also, my ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext doesn't contain "Persons" (I only have Persons property in my implementation of DbContext -> `DbSet<PersonModel> Persons`, but DbSet doesn't have Detach().)

Comment: I definitely couldn't reproduce the problem under the circumstances you described. I've also updated the `Detach` code sample.